# Active Directory group membership audit

Tags: active-directory

We have different user types: i.e. agent, team lead, QA, trainer etc.
Each of those is supposed to have certain AD group membership as a baseline:
Agent - group: A, B, C, D, E
Team Lead: F, G, H, X, Y, Z

The issue is that some agents are being transferred from one project to a different one and no group memberships are removed, they're just adding.

The question is if there is a way (i.e. by powershell) or a tool to audit these (not one by one) - check current group membership against a baseline?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is trivially implemented in Windows PowerShell - assuming that the user object in AD reflects their "type". Do you have any further details? Do the users have up-to-date business titles? `employeeType` attribute in use? Special notes in the `description` field? Perhaps try describing how would you manually assess one of these users?

Comment: Hi Mathias,
In terms of details we're at the very beginning of this and looking for suggestions at that point. Just checked in AD and they do not seem to have titles, the way we identify them is by the container that they are residing in i.e. Agents/OpsABC/ProdUsers/domain.ads. We have the default groups that they supposed to have and the current ones can be checked in AD directly or in powershell. Hope that sheds some more light.

Answer (score 0):

I have set a baseline based on the tittle

```
Get-ADUser -Properties title -Filter {title -like "StackEngineer"} | select Name,groupscope | Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'
```

Run the above command and got the all the user which has tittle "StackEngineer”.

[image]

Output --

[image]

Now by manually we can find group membership of every user

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership A| select name,groupscope
```

[image]